# BigCommerce Stencil - Category Resource Depth

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm working on a store with 14,500 categories. It takes over 8 seconds to load the homepage.

I'm trying to limit the level of subcategories that are pulled in as a resource, thus dramatically decreasing the amount of data being loaded on each page bc I only need 1 level on the nav menu.

I don't see anything in the control panel, front-matter, or config file that would do this. I know this was in Blueprint, so I figured it would be in the config file but no luck.

Is this possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I changed the store back to a Blueprint theme, and changed the category display setting to only show 1 level. Then switched back to my Stencil theme. Debugged the local JSON locally and that did the trick. Now the store is only loading 1 level deep of categories. I have no idea why this setting was overlooked in Stencil and not included in the config file.

Comment: I'll raise this with the team. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: No problem. It sped the site up quite a bit!